# deploy openstack-dashboard and cinder with juju using lxc

Tags: juju

During the deploy of openstack-dashboard with juju, using the command:

`juju deploy --to lxc:0 openstack-dashboard`

The charm rest in pending. In `juju status` I see that:

```
$: juju status -e maas**
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14
    dns-name: Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode0.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-d0d2b128-7c75-11e4-b0f5-52540065461a/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1024M tags=virtual
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14
    dns-name: Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode1.maas
    instance-id: manual:Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode1.maas
    series: trusty
    containers:
      1/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        dns-name: 10.0.3.203
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        dns-name: 10.0.3.211
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        dns-name: 10.0.3.254
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-2
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/3:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        dns-name: 10.0.3.225
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-3
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/4:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        dns-name: 10.0.3.170
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-4
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/5:
        agent-state-info: 'error executing "lxc-clone": rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-5/rootfs/usr/lib/python2.7/test/regrtest.py":
          No space left on device (28); rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
          receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]; lxc_container: rsyncing /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs
          to /var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-5/rootfs; lxc_container: Error copying
          storage; clone failed'
        instance-id: pending
        series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=994M
  "2":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14
    dns-name: Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode2.maas
    instance-id: manual:Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode2.maas
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=994M
services:
  glance:
    charm: cs:trusty/glance-9
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - glance
    units:
      glance/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: 1/lxc/3
        open-ports:
        - 9292/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.3.225
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-16
    exposed: false
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: "0"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: Ubuntu1404CloudMaaSRCMasterCloudMaaSRCNode0.maas
  keystone:
    charm: cs:trusty/keystone-9
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - keystone
    units:
      keystone/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: 1/lxc/1
        public-address: 10.0.3.211
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/mysql-13
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: 1/lxc/0
        public-address: 10.0.3.203
  nova-cloud-controller:
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-50
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - nova-cloud-controller
    units:
      nova-cloud-controller/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: 1/lxc/2
        open-ports:
        - 3333/tcp
        - 8773/tcp
        - 8774/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.3.254
  openstack-dashboard:
    charm: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-8
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - openstack-dashboard
    units:
      openstack-dashboard/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1/lxc/6
  rabbitmq-server:
    charm: cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-19
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - rabbitmq-server
    units:
      rabbitmq-server/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.20.14
        machine: 1/lxc/4
        public-address: 10.0.3.170
```

I waited a long time and nothing happened. I decided to remove the service e destroy it. 
I've re-run the command again but the error doesn't go away and I've another one:

```
  1/lxc/5:
    agent-state-info: 'error executing "lxc-clone": rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-5/rootfs/usr/lib/python2.7/test/regrtest.py":
      No space left on device (28); rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
      receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]; lxc_container: rsyncing /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs
      to /var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-5/rootfs; lxc_container: Error copying
      storage; clone failed'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
  1/lxc/6:
    agent-state-info: 'error executing "lxc-clone": rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-6/rootfs/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc_data/topics.pyc":
      No space left on device (28); rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
      receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]; lxc_container: rsyncing /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs
      to /var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-6/rootfs; lxc_container: Error copying
      storage; clone failed'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
```

For cinder I receive the same error:

`juju deploy --to lxc:0 cinder`

```
  1/lxc/7:
    agent-state-info: 'error executing "lxc-clone": rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-7/rootfs/usr/lib/python2.7/test/pystone.py":
      No space left on device (28); rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
      receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]; lxc_container: rsyncing /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs
      to /var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-1-lxc-7/rootfs; lxc_container: Error copying
      storage; clone failed'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=994M
```

---

**How can I resolve or clean the `lxc` container?**

Comment: I recommend going to `#juju` IRC channel on Freenode.  There is a developer almost always around willing to help.  Ref this post.

Comment: Are you still looking for answer? If no, did you arrive at any complete answer. If yes, please complete your answer. If no, please let us know

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer about that question has been found, we can clean the container directly from `juju-gui` removing the container. As reported from this screenshot:

[image]

For the deploy of openstack-dashboard using LXC I continue to receive the same error.

Comment: I just realized this was a partial resolve.  You should update your original answer until you have a complete solution.